# How to end this loop / logically end pseudocode

Tags: loops, logic, pseudocode, do-while, records

I'm writing a pseudocode program to read customer record, determine their account type, and then output their name and amount owed at the end. I wrote a program (almost done) I'm just not sure how to loop it until there are no more records left. Can you guys help me out? My output at the end is just supposed to be Customer Name and Amount Owed. Thanks.

```
read_customer_record 
get num_of_records
    get customer_name
get account_type
get num_basic_channels
get num_premium_channels
calculate_rate (calcR) 
calculate_totals (calcT)
output(outp)


END

Calculate_rate (calcR)
IF account_type = personal
Basic_rateP = $5
Pre_rateP = $10
    ELSE
        Basic_rateB = $7.50
        Pre_rateB = $12.50
END

Calculate_totals (calcT, calcR)
IF account_type = personal
total = (num_basic_channels * Basic_rateP) + (num_premium_channels * Pre_rateP)
    ELSE
total = (num_basic_channels * Basic_rateB) + (num_premium_channels * Pre_rateB)
END

output (
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

**>>>** Print Customer Name and Amount owed , till Customer Name is not equal to Null.

If I write the code in C++, it will look something like this.

```
for(i=0;CustomerName[i]!=NULL;i++)  //Loop till there is some Customer Name exists
{
cout<<CustomerName[i]<<"\t"<<AmountOwed[i];  //Printing out the Data
}
```

It will stop when there will be no Customer Remaining and when there is not Customer , obviously there is no Amount Owed.

Comment: So where can I initiate a similar for loop? Does the rest of my logic make sense?

Comment: I wrote the loop for printing out the results.If you want to do some calculations on a record , you can simple use Arrays.Such as total[i]. Yes , your Logic does makes sense but make sure that you use Brackets } carefully when dealing with If Else statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wrap a WHILE statement around your main routine. The way to do that depends on where you are reading the customer record from.

Case 1: In many contexts you can only tell that you have finished processing the input stream by attempting to read past the end. In that case your pseudocode might look like:

```
read_customer_record 
while the previous read succeeded
    get num_of_records
    get customer_name
    get account_type
    get num_basic_channels
    get num_premium_channels
    calculate_rate (calcR) 
    calculate_totals (calcT)
    output(outp)
    read_customer_record
end
```

Case 2: In other contexts you can tell before a read whether there is something left to read from the input stream. In that case your pseudocode might look like:

```
while there are more customer records to process
    read_customer_record
    get num_of_records
    get customer_name
    get account_type
    get num_basic_channels
    get num_premium_channels
    calculate_rate (calcR) 
    calculate_totals (calcT)
    output(outp)
end
```